# Is it correct update client side object with angular.copy response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have an import functionality client side page with display 'Save button' or 'Saved lable' depends on entity`s id.

[image]

Here is my `save` function: response of it is created on server side, stored into database and selected after that object (after save i'd like to display stored value, which one should already have `id` (auto_increment PK)):

[image]

So, after i saved order and got response with stored value, i need to update passed as argument order (to set order's id, so that's saving button gone invisible and `saved` label showed).

I did it with `angular.copy(entity, order)`, but is it correct and are there other practices with applying and updating `view's` object from response.

Code here:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in model.importedOrders">
        <td ng-bind="$index + 1"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.externalOrderId"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.customerFullName"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.customerAddress"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.customerPhone"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.orderItems[0].item.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.orderItems[0].purchasePrice.format('$n')" nowrap></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.orderItems[0].sellingPrice.format('$n')" nowrap></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.vendor.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.manager.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.driver.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.deliveryPrice.format('$n')" nowrap></td>
        <td ng-bind="order.note"></td>
        <td>
            <a ng-if="!order.id"
               ng-click="actions.save(order)"
               href="#"
               class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Сохранить</a>

            <span ng-if="order.id"
                class="label label-success">Сохранено</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Js function;

```
save: function(order) {
    order$.save({ entity: order }).then(
        function(msg) {
            var entity = coalesce(msg, 'data.order');
            angular.copy(entity, order);
        }, function(msg) {
            toaster$.pop('error', 'Ошибка на этапе сохранения заказа', coalesce(msg, 'data.description'));
        });
}
```

A little helper function:

```
function coalesce(obj, path) {
    return $parse(path)(obj);
}
```

Comment: how can I post an answer modifying your image? Always write the code instead of posting image.

Comment: Yeap, you are right, updated with code

Comment: @FSou1 it should be `entity = angular.copy(order);` then it will persist data

Comment: @pankajparkar, which problem does it solve? We need to update passed to function `save` argument `order`, isn't it?